# Does anyone have a .sh script to scan recursively the current folder for 0 byte files and place them into text file?

Tags: scripts, directory, sh

I am looking for a simple `.sh` script which can scan the current folder and sub folders recursively for 0 byte files. I know this can be done in only a few lines, but I'm quite noobian on the command line of Linux.
It would be great if the output could be listed to a text file, like `> 0byte.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find` command:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -empty > zerobyte.txt
```

- `-type f` look only for files
- `-empty` finds empty files

Comment: thanks ! it works ! i changed the path so that i could scan the current folder and all of its subfolders  - find ./ -type f -empty > 0byte.txt